composable is not identified by android studio ide
When creating NavHost inside the content block android studio can not identify composable:   i have added navigation dependency and even import statement also ..
thanks in advance
CLICK HIGHLIGHTED TEXT(BLUE) TO GET IDEA WHAT I AM TALKING ABOUT.
I tried to open new project then take a sample demo but it also didn't work.
This is build.gradle.kts
`plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.compose)
//    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
  }

android {
namespace = "com.example.navigation"
compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.navigation"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
}

dependencies {
val nav_version = "2.8.2"

// Jetpack Compose integration
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")

implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
testImplementation(libs.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}`

And this is where it is stuck.
package com.example.navigation

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
 import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.navigation.ui.theme.NavigationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContent {
        NavigationTheme {
            val navController= rememberNavController()
            Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {   innerPadding ->
                Greeting(
                    name = "Android",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                    navController=navController
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
}






@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier =   Modifier,navController: NavController) {
NavHost(navController,"Home"){
   composable("Home"){

   }
}
}

Here in this composable is highlighted in red....

We need to see some code.

Please edit your question to provide your build.gradle or build.gradle.kts files where you have specified the Navigation for Compose dependencies.

tried my best to explain situation

https://i.sstatic.net/v8ciPtEo.jpg

It seems that you have your dependencies set correctly. One thing you can try is adding the import statement yourself.
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable

had already tried it but nothing

well one thing I've tried is to check for composable.kt in the dependency file  but seems it is also not there....     while import statement is able to identify the correct path.
